# Is "Tamasi" a name of Durga?

Tags: name, durga

Where does this name come from?  Is the name being used in an endearing or otherwise positive manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, in Devi-Maahatmya (Chapter 11, mantra 23), we get:

> Medhe Saraswati Vare Bhuti Babravi **Tamasi**" meaning , O Devi,you are Medha, Saraswati, Varaniyaa, Parama-Aiswaryarupa, and Taamasi.

Is is a part of the famous hymn (Devyah stutih) sung by the devataas to praise Devi after Shumbha-badha.

Devi is Trigunatmika. In Sattwaguna, She becomes Sattwiki which is meant by the term Parama Aishwarya(Maha-Lakshmi),, In Rajoguna She becomes (Maha)Saraswati and in Tamo-Guna,She becomes Taamasi(Maha-Kali). She is called Turiya or Trigunaatita too in that book.

So "Taamasi' is used as a praise.

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm that it is only Durga's name.  The answer from Bhagavata Purana doesn't seem to be using a correct translation:

https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205_djvu.txt

> CHAPTER TWENTYFIVE
>
> ( Description of Sahkar$ana — the Serpent Seta )
>
> •Sri Suka said :
>
> 1. At the lowest extreme below Patala, at a distance of
>    thirty thousand Tojanas , abides a part-manifestation of the
>    Lord which is dominated by the Tomas only. It is also well-
>    known as Ananta. Followers of the Satvata School call it
>    Sankar$ana as, being characterised by ego and presiding over
>    by ( I’-ness, it brings about the unification between the subject
>    (the Seer) and the object (the seen) .

https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish#page/n769/mode/2up

is a cleaner source, but I doesn't seem to allow copy paste.

The Sanskrit original has nothing about Siva:

> ŚB 5.25.1
>
> श्रीशुक उवाच ।
>
> तस्य मूलदेशे त्रिंशद्योजनसहस्रान्तर आस्ते या वै कला भगवतस्तामसी समाख्यातानन्त इति
> सात्वतीया द्रष्टृदृश्ययोः सङ्कर्षणमहमित्यभिमानलक्षणं यं सङ्कर्षणमित्याचक्षते ॥ ५.२५.१ ॥

Comment: It IS a name of Durga.But sanskrit words have different meanings and so it can be applied to any female entity ( Kalaa here). krishna means black also and used in many cases to mean that. Same is the case here.

Answer (score -1):

> Where does this name come from? Is the name being used in an endearing or otherwise positive manner?

**It is a name of Vishnu and is used in a positive manner because Shiva worships him.**

From the *[Srimad Bhagavatam](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/25/1/)*:

> Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī said to Mahārāja Parīkṣit: My dear King, approximately 240,000 miles beneath the planet Pātāla lives another incarnation of the Supreme Personality of Godhead. He is the expansion of Lord Viṣṇu known as Lord Ananta or Lord Saṅkarṣaṇa. He is always in the transcendental position, **but because He is worshiped by Lord Śiva, the deity of tamo-guṇa or darkness, He is sometimes called tāmasī.** Lord Ananta is the predominating Deity of the material mode of ignorance as well as the false ego of all conditioned souls. When a conditioned living being thinks, “I am the enjoyer, and this world is meant to be enjoyed by me,” this conception of life is dictated to him by Saṅkarṣaṇa. Thus the mundane conditioned soul thinks himself the Supreme Lord.